# How to send images on Parse without using a query?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

Is there a way to directly send a list of users an image using parse on Xcode? I am able to send the image using a query, but I'm worried that searching through every image that is stored in my class, matching it to the user that sent it, and then retrieving that image is going to take a while and I would like it to be there quickly.

This is the way I am currently saving the images to the database:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString * username =  currentUser.username;
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image, 1.0f);
PFFile * newImageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.jpeg" data:imageData];
PFObject * newImage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Images"];

[newImage setObject:newImageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];
[newImage setObject:name forKey:@"username"];
[newImage setObject:object forKey:@"sendImageToFollowing"];

[newImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {}
```

Comment: Are you looking to send the image directly to those users via a push notification? If you could explain a little more about your use case, it would help find an answer!

Comment: Yea! I would like the image to be loaded in the app when the user gets the push notification which I will configure later, but for now I just wanted to see if there was a more effective way of presenting an image that is sent out by a user to the other users that the image was meant to be sent out to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the image to Parse.com and sending a push that references that image in the push's payload is the way to go, for two reasons:

1. It's impossible to send more than a few kb via a push message. They are very small by design, so you have to pass a reference to something.
2. I'm guessing you want the image saved anyways :)

Save the image, get the objectId from Parse, send that as part of the custom push notification payload. You can create a custom dictionary and send it with your push. For more on that, see here:

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-customizing-your-notifications.

If you want to get the objectId very quickly, you can get it from the query itself when it succeeds:

```
[newImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    //Get the image objectId here
    NSString *objectIdString = newImage.objectId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for your response! However, the only part I am worried about is retrieving that objectId because I will have to search though every image in my class with the method that Parse suggests. Maybe this is done very quickly, and I shouldn't worry about this?